# combine 2 fields in 1 to use it in the "group by" section of the reports

Tags: formula

is it possible to combine two fields in one and use that field to group by in reports? for example, i would like to combine ee id and ee name fields in 1 and show as 1 field in the "group by" section on reports.

Answer (score 2):

Lena,

You can create a **custom formula text field** in your object and combine both these fields in it.

Lets say if your field types of ee id is Number and ee name is Text, then your formula field be like

```
Text(EE_ID__c) & Name
```

Then you can summarise your report based on  the formula field.

Comment: this is great, thanks so much for the speedy response.